# SQL query with SUM and GROUP

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum

I have the following table backup which combines data of hours, persons, type of backup and date of backup:

```
data        |   type   |   persons   |  hours
==============================================
2015-06-12      15           4            8
2015-06-12      15           4            8
2015-06-12      15           4            8
2015-06-12      15           4            8
2015-06-13      14           2            4
2015-06-13      14           2            4
```

I'm trying to write a query which will return following result:

```
       data     |   type   |   persons   |  hours
    ==============================================
    2015-06-12      15           4            32
    2015-06-13      14           2            8
```

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT "data", "type", SUM("hours"), "persons" FROM "backup" GROUP BY "type", "data", "persons" ORDER BY "data"
```

but it does'nt work the way I want :(

**EDIT:**

after using of this query:

```
SELECT "data", "type", "persons", SUM("hours") AS "hours" FROM "backup" WHERE "project" = '2000030' GROUP BY "type", "data", "persons" ORDER BY "data"
```

SQL returns this data:

```
   data    |   type  |  persons  |  hours
==========================================
2011-12-16 | 2003774 |     9     |   12
2011-12-16 | 2003774 |    10     |   12
```

but there should be:

```
   data    |   type  |  persons  |  hours
==========================================
2011-12-16 | 2003774 |     9     |   54
```

In DB I have 9 records (one record per person), in each person cell is 9, and in each hours cell is 9. I need to sum hours per date and per type of backup (support).

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the query. What output do you get? . . .

Comment: the query you are sharing will give you the desired result you are showing  Are you perhaps simplifying it too much that you have eliminated the issue?

Comment: Please check edited details above.

Answer (score 1):

The correct query is

```
SELECT "data", "type", "persons", SUM("hours") FROM "backup" GROUP BY "type", "data", "persons" ORDER BY "data"
```

"persons" and SUM("hours") are switched. This is the only problem, based on expected result.

update:
If you expect to have one row per type try following:

```
SELECT "data", "type", MAX("persons"), SUM("hours") FROM "backup" GROUP BY "type", "data" ORDER BY "data"
```

Comment: I'm affraid it's not. I also need to use "GROUP BY data, type, persons" part (because of: ERROR:  column "data" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function). Then query returns duplicated records, ex.:
2011-12-16 | 2003774 | 9 | 12 and
2011-12-16 | 2003774 | 10 | 12

:(

Comment: I have appended missing part to the answer (copy and paste mistake). Do you still have a problem?

Comment: I saw - thanks Emil, but still same problem as I wrote before. I don't know why, but records are duplicated with different persons and hours values. I tried with SELECT DISTINCT but it didn't help.

Comment: As I understand by dublicacting you mean you need to have one row per type. If so, you need to decide what would you your aggregate rule for person column. Lets say you need to show maximum, then aggregate with MAX(person). Average is also possible rule in your case.

Comment: I think now it works fine, thanks a lot Emil! I totally forgot about MAX rule. Tomorrow (now is 1AM) I'll check data returned by query. Regs.

Comment: Ok, I just checked. SUM isn't good, I should receive 54 persono-hours (9 persons * 6 hours), but query returns 10 persons and 24 hours :(

Comment: Would you explain more why 9 persons and why 6 hours? I don't see such data in your example. Are these 6 hours fixed (per day)? Why 9 persons and not 10 persons? may be you need MIN instead of MAX? Would you give your business requirement? May be if you give detailed explanation about each column, this will help to identify aggregation rules.